# Noms composés avec ou sans trait d'union

Tags: orthographe, lexique, mots-composés, trait-d-union

Existe-t-il une liste exhaustive des noms composés français qui peuvent s'écrire avec ou sans trait d'union ?

Par exemple :

- autoentrepreneur et auto-entrepreneur
- agroalimentaire et agro-alimentaire

Comment: Par liste exhaustive, tu veux dire un dictionnaire? Parce que oui, chaque mots composés sont dans le dictionnaire, alors..

Comment: Oui, les mots-composés sont dans le dictionnaire. Mais j'aimerais la liste de ceux qui ont deux orthographes autorisées.

Comment: Peut-être ce livre-ci (en regardant les pages données comme aperçu, on voit la variation pour *auto-couchette*) : http://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_1995_num_108_1_5322

Comment: En effet ce livre est très intéressant ! Et il note que 29% des mots avec traits d'union acceptent une variante soudée. Soit un total de 5 000 mots (page 80). J'aimerais justement savoir s'il existe une liste des 5 000.

Comment: Le livre que Paul Picard propose a comme sous-titre _La variation graphique et les rectifications de l'orthographe française (1990)_. Donc on demande avant ou incluant ces rectifications ? Les dictionnaires ne s'entend(ai)ent pas tous; ce serait une liste basée sur une différence d'opinion et non une règle. À croiser ou utiliser par ceux qui répondent : [1](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emploi_du_trait_d'union_pour_les_pr%C3%A9fixes_en_fran%C3%A7ais), [2](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3190), [3](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=1&th_id=173).

Answer (score 1):

**En général les mots composés ont un (ou des) trait d'union.** Sans trait d'union mais avec un espace, il s'agit d'expressions.

La réforme de 1990 a modifié certaines règles (disparition de nombreux cas de tirets, et soudure des mots), tout en autorisant les 2 formes:

- [Rectifications de l'orthographe sur le site de l'Académie Française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/sites/academie-francaise.fr/files/rectifications_1990.pdf)
- [Renouvo avec règles simplifiées](http://www.renouvo.org/regles.php)

Ce qui suit concerne les formes avec tirets:

Pour les mots composés avec des tirets: théoriquement **oui** : on *pourrait* constituer une telle liste, car tous les mots acceptables sont listés exhaustivement dans des dictionnaires.

En pratique, **il y a énormément de combinaisons possible ou acceptables**, et avec des règles de composition des mots existants, autant ou plus. Donc il paraît impossible de les recenser toutes, à l'exception des formes particulières.

Il y a plusieurs formes de mots composés, la plupart peuvent perdre leur tiret dans la réforme de l'orthographe de 1990 (à l'exception des numéraux) :

- les formes verbe à la troisième personne de l'indicatif présent - COD (sans article), certains à sens littéral : *pèse-personne*, *essuie-mains*, *porte-serviettes*  d'autres à sens figuré : *lèche-vitrines*, *abat-jour*. **On peut les créer soi-même avec des verbes courants** (pose, range, attrape, porte, ...)
- quelques formes verbe-adverbe : *passe-partout*
- les formes adjectif-substantif, assez nombreuses : *plate-forme*, *grand-mère*.
- des formes substantif-substantif, plus rares dans le vocabulaire courant : *voiture-balai* . **Le domaine animalier ou scientifique (chimie) en contient ou en produit des milliers** : *poisson-chat*, *requin-marteau*.
- les formes préfixe-substantif (le préfixe joue le rôle d'adjectif), où le préfixe est générique : micro, macro, supra, infra, électro, pseudo, demi, ... . **Cette construction peut être quasiment déclinée avec n'importe quel substantif** : *micro-voiture*, *pseudo-professeur*,
- des formes particulières, quasiment des expressions : *pot-au-feu*.
- quelques formes avec des prépositions (à notamment) : *à-valoir*, *à-coup*
- les adjectifs numéraux

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à la question posée.

Comment: En complément : la réforme de 1990 dont on parle actuellement a un peu changer la donne quant aux mots composés (http://bit.ly/20R12gl) : pour résumé, la graphie recommandée est la graphie soudée (sans trait d'union), sauf pour quelques cas où elle est obligatoire

Comment: @Garf365 merci, j'ai complété.

Comment: Merci @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina. Mais en effet ça ne répond pas à la question posée. J'aimerais savoir s'il y a une liste avec les mots composés pour lesquels trait d'union et soudure sont acceptés. Donc une liste avec auto-entrepreneur (car autoentrepreneur est accepté) mais par gréco-romain (car grécoromain n'est pas accepté).

Peut-être qu'une telle liste est liée à la réforme de 1990 (et encore, autoentrepreneur n'existait pas à l'époque !).

Answer (score 1):

J'ignore l'intérêt d'une telle liste, mais je dirais que non puisqu'il semble compliqué de la constituer.

Le [lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_des_r%C3%A8gles_typographiques_en_usage_%C3%A0_l%27Imprimerie_nationale) est suivi par l'Académie Française [pour l'impression de son dictionnaire](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/actualites/dictionnaire-de-lacademie-francaise-tome-3) et il stipule que tout mot composé nécessite des traits d'union.

Les exemples cités par l'auteur du post sont des mots récents, donc on peut plutôt dire que l'usage du trait d'union se perd, mais cela ne respecte pas la règle de l'académie.

Ça se mord d'ailleurs un peu la queue dans la mesure où l'Imprimerie prêche le trait d'union partout, alors que l'Académie a réformé le trait d'union. Quand bien même la théorie autoriserait l'absence de trait d'union, ce serait erroné de le voir imprimé !

Comme dit guillaume girod dans sa réponse, la réforme (qui fait actuellement du bruit) de 1990 simplifie ces règles, mais si elle ne contient pas cette liste, il faudra demander à un sage de la faire pour être réellement exhaustif !